# Is the OES_framebuffer_object extension broken on Tegra based devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, tegra

We port some OpenGL ES 1.x code which use FBO extension (**GL_OES_framebuffer_object**) to Android and got the problems with **Tegra** based devices (**Tegra 2, Tegra 3**). The problem is that while devices report **GL_OES_framebuffer_object** extension in the list of supported extensions, the part of functionality seems to be broken and in particular, `glGetIntegerv()` function doesn't accept any extension-related constants (e.g. `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES`) reporting `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. At the same time, other extension-related functions are work fine.

- Is that an known issue?
- Is there well known workaround?
- Does someone face this problem too?

The devices we test on are Nexus7 and Acer A500.

Comment: I can confirm that a game, built with MonoGame, runs fine on Nexus 4 and Galaxy Tab 2, but also fails on Nexus 7 and Acer A500, when creating framebuffers and render targets. I've not managed to find a workaround yet. So I think this is an issue with Tegra chipsets :(. I noticed that the Adreno 320 and PowerVR support GL_OES_depth24, while the Tegra does not. So was thinking of setting the depth to 16 on Tegra devices to see if that works. I won't have time to test it for another couple of day.

Comment: @Dominique: Tegra only supports 16 bit depth buffers.

Comment: @kusma setting the depth to 16 appears to fix the issue on Tegra devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that on Tegra devices you need to set the bit depth to 16, for it to work. Once we did that in MonoGame, games worked correctly on Nexus 7 and Acer500.

D.